# bootstrap make login form to the left on modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a project with bootstrap. There is a login form when I click to the "Sign In" button. 
Image is here: http://www.pixentral.com/pics/17N1Z8UG0Lb3F3HeREEtTo4RRHxL.jpg

How Can I make the login form to the left? I want to show the login form on the Modal.
Here is my complete HTML:http://textuploader.com/oq5j
You can look my project with this HTML. Just copy and paste.

Question: How Can I make the login form to the left? I want to show the login form on the Modal.

Comment: Post your code in your question.

Comment: It is very long. I added link: http://textuploader.com/oq5j

Comment: anyone knows the answer?

Comment: Doesn't matter if your code is too long, post at least the most relevant part of it, if that service stops working, people in the future won't be able to see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right where you start your modal you have this line of code:

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:40px">
```

The `container` class is specifying a width of 970px. I suggest removing that class and adding a new one where you can specify a new width. Once you do that you will still need to play around with the Row and Column class you are using.

Comment: can you provide example?

Comment: Well to make your form table fill the width of the modal container you don't even need to have "col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" class. You can read more about it here http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/